# Objective function return NaN in fcm function (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, function, fuzzy

I used the fcm function in Matlab. In the function stepfcmp, I modified the function with if the iter=1 and assigned the values for center. But after the first iteration, the objective function values returns NaN in the following iteration:

```
Iteration count = 1, obj. fcn = 51.351334
Iteration count = 2, obj. fcn = NaN
Iteration count = 3, obj. fcn = NaN
Iteration count = 4, obj. fcn = NaN
```

How to fix it?

Comment: please provide some reproducible code in your question:)

Comment: I think may some of the values of my data points are exactly the values of the centers which I put .

Comment: So, you solved your own question?

Comment: Not yet. I just make a guess and still struggling with this issue.